# Why does my access token do not return my events and the Graph API explorer access token does?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Using the graph api explorer access token as below with scopes `read_stream` and `user_events` it does return my created events.

```
App ID: 145634995501895 : Graph API Explorer  
User ID: xxxx: xxxx  
Issued: Unknown  
Expires: 1361847600 (in about an hour)  
Valid:  True  
Origin: Unknown  
Scopes: read_stream user_events
```

But when I'm using my app and authenticate it through web browser, it does not return any events.

```
App ID: xxx: xxxx  
User ID: xxx: xxxx  
Issued: 1361843644 (about a minute ago)  
Expires: 1367027644 (in about 2 months)  
Valid:  True  
Origin: Web  
Scopes: manage_pages read_friendlists read_stream user_events user_questions
```

Here's my fql:

```
fql?q={'posts':'SELECT post_id,target_id,actor_id,tagged_ids,with_tags, message,description,attachment, likes, comments,type, updated_time, created_time, action_links, attribution FROM stream WHERE source_id=me() order by updated_time desc LIMIT 25', 
       'options':'SELECT  id, question_id, votes,name FROM question_option where question_id in (SELECT attachment.fb_object_id FROM #posts)', 
       'voters':'SELECT option_id, voter_id FROM question_option_votes WHERE option_id IN (SELECT id FROM #options)', 
       'question':'SELECT id, owner, question FROM question WHERE id in (SELECT attachment.fb_object_id FROM #posts)',
       'profile':'SELECT id, pic_square, type, name, username, url FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT target_id,actor_id,tagged_ids,with_tags,comments.comment_list.fromid FROM #posts)  OR id in (SELECT voter_id FROM #voters)'
      }
```